# GLES20 Updating draw() bitmap

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, augmented-reality

The situation I'm in is hard to describe. What I want to do is that on button click OpenGL renderer could change its bitmap to specified. Its either something wrong with my draw() method, or probably with changing renderer image.

Some additional info: 
I'm using MAXST AR on Android device to track image and show another image on to live image. And with button clicks on screen, I want to change currently displayed image to another. I tried everything I can and now I'm willing to get some good ideas how to solve my problem

My draw() method :

```
@Override
public void draw() {
    GLES20.glUseProgram(shaderProgramId);

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            0, vertexBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            0, textureCoordBuff);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

    Matrix.setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(modelMatrix, 0, translation, 0, rotation, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(modelMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0, scale, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(modelMatrix, 0, transform, 0, modelMatrix, 0);


    Matrix.multiplyMM(localMvpMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, false, localMvpMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(textureHandle, 0);
    glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureNames[0]);

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, INDEX_BUF.length,
            GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);

    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);
    glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

setTextureBitmap() method :

```
public void setTextureBitmap(Bitmap texture) {
    glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureNames[0]);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, texture, 0);
    texture.recycle();
}
```

next(), previous() methodes :

```
fun next() {
    if(current < allSize()) {
        current++
        val bitmap = MaxstARUtil.getBitmapFromAsset(Functions.randomNote(), activity.assets)
        var text = textAsBitmap(title, 72f, Color.BLACK, bitmap)
        if(current > 0 && current < desc.size) {
            println(desc.get(current))
            text = textAsBitmap(desc.get(current), 72f, Color.WHITE, bitmap)
        } else if(current >= desc.size) {
            currentRenderer!!.setTextureBitmap(bitmap)
            return
        }
        currentRenderer!!.setTextureBitmap(text)
    }
    println(current)
}

fun previous() {
    if(current > 0) {
        current--
        val bitmap = MaxstARUtil.getBitmapFromAsset(Functions.randomNote(), activity.assets)
        var text = textAsBitmap(title, 72f, Color.BLACK, bitmap)
        if(current > 0 && current < desc.size) {
            text = textAsBitmap(desc.get(current), 72f, Color.WHITE, bitmap)
        } else if(current >= desc.size) {
            currentRenderer!!.setTextureBitmap(bitmap)
            return
        }
        currentRenderer!!.setTextureBitmap(text)
    }
    println(current)
}
```

Comment: You've well explained what you want to do, but what is the issue? What does not work?

Comment: @Rabbid76 What doesn't work is that it only shows one of the bitmap, when I call next() nothing happens and it should change current bitmap with new